# Why this prove the independence of these events?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm studying [A First Course in Probability](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134753119) from  Sheldon Ross, and I'm trying to solve this exercise from page 171:

[image]

**My solution:**

a. $P(E_{3,4}|E_{1,2})= \frac{P(E_{3,4}E_{1,2})}{P(E_{1,2})}=\frac{1/365^2}{1/365}=\frac{1}{365}$

b. $P(E_{1,3}|E_{1,2})= \frac{P(E_{3,4}E_{1,2})}{P(E_{1,2})}=\frac{1/365^2}{1/365}=\frac{1}{365}$

c. $P(E_{2,3}|E_{1,2}\cap E_{1,3}) = \frac{P(E_{2,3}E_{1,2}E_{1,3})}{P(E_{1,2}E_{1,3})}=\frac{1/365^3}{1/365^2}=\frac{1}{365}$

**My questions:**

1. Are my calculations right?
2. Why this prove the independence of these events? can I use a similar argument to show the independence of events in general?

Comment: I agree with Graham Kemp's answer, especially part c.  Part c demonstrates that $E_{2,3}$ is affected by (i.e. is **dependent** on) the combination of events $E_{1,2}$ and $E_{1,3}.$

Comment: Which is a statement about the *(some-adjective)* independence of the *set* of three events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a. $\checkmark$ Indeed. When given that persons 1 and 2 share a birthdate, there is no influence on whether persons 3 and 4 do too. $$\mathsf P(E_{3,4}\mid E_{1,2})=\dfrac 1{365}$$

b. $\checkmark$ Indeed.  When given that persons 1 and 2 share a birthdate, there is no influence on whether person 3 shares a birthdate with person 1. $$\mathsf P(E_{1,3}\mid E_{1,2})=\dfrac 1{365}$$

c. $\times$. Nope.  When given that persons 1 and 2 share a birthdate, *and* that 1 and 3 do too, that makes it *certain* that 2 and 3 share a birth date.  $$\mathsf P(E_{2,3}\mid E_{1,2}\cap E_{1,3})=1$$

Comment: yeaahhh, of course!!!! Thank you very much.

Comment: So am I right in these statements:

1.So the events are not completely independent, the book calls "almost independent"
2. The part 1 and 2 shows independence because the probability of the conditional is the same as the probability without a conditional

Comment: "Almost independent" is not a formal term. Exercises (a) and (b) demonstrate that this is a set of *pairwise* independent events, while (c) demonstrates that this is **not** a set of *mutually* independent events. @user42912